# Terraform Multiple Instances of kubernetes_job

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

The routine is to Terraform a kubernetes_job resource.

The idea is run multiple instances of the Kubernetes job using the count function.

The expected behaviour is to create 3 jobs and run them in parallel. Each job will be passed in an argument from an array element using the counter.

However - the jobs don't run in parallel, instead in the job log, they appear to be running sequentially.

Here is the config:

```
resource "kubernetes_job" "rotate_eks_nodes" {

  count = length(local.eks_asg)

  metadata {
    name      = "rotate-eks-nodes-job-${count.index}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.rotate_eks_nodes.metadata[0].name
  }

  spec {
    parallelism                = 1
    completions                = length(local.eks_asg)
    backoff_limit              = 0
    ttl_seconds_after_finished = 1000

    template {
      metadata {
      }
      spec {

        container {
          security_context {
            run_as_user = 0
          }
          name    = "rotate-eks-nodes-job"
          image   = "artifactory.ie/alpine-awscli:1.0.1"
          command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"Starting Rotate EKS Nodes Job ${count.index}\" && /script/rotate.sh ${local.eks_asg[count.index]} ${local.eks_asg_desired_size[count.index]} && echo \"Completed Rotate EKS Nodes Job ${count.index}\""]
          
          volume_mount {
            name       = kubernetes_config_map.rotate_script.metadata[0].name
            mount_path = "/script"
          }
        }

        volume {
          name = kubernetes_config_map.rotate_script.metadata[0].name
          config_map {
            name         = kubernetes_config_map.rotate_script.metadata[0].name
            default_mode = "0755"
          }
        }

        service_account_name = kubernetes_service_account.rotate_eks_nodes.metadata[0].name
      }
    }
  }
  wait_for_completion = true
  timeouts {
    create = "15m"
    update = "15m"
  }
}
```

Any ideas or pointers on this would be greatly appreciated :-)

## Edit 1

Parallelism - by setting it to 3, then you get 3 instances of each count, so you end up with 9 jobs rather than 3.

```
[ components ] > aws-vault exec build -- kubectl get po -n rotate-eks-nodes
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rotate-eks-nodes-job-0-qwkrk   1/1     Running   0          74s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-0-qxfs2   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-0-wd7p5   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-1-5hjnb   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-1-db98p   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-1-h7hfh   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-2-5h4b6   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-2-jmrjx   1/1     Running   0          73s
rotate-eks-nodes-job-2-lp86b   1/1     Running   0          73s
```

## Edit 2

Wait For Completion - by setting to false, Terraform creates the resource and then completes rather than waiting for the Kubernetes job to complete.

## Working Solution

Adjust the resource config like so.

```
parallelism                = 1
completions                = 1
wait_for_completion = false
```

The actual issue was a bug within the rotate.sh script.

Comment: And if you set `parallelism` to 3, i.e., `length(local.eks_asg)`?

Comment: You have `wait_for_completion` as true, set it as false so Terraform can spawn all the jobs in parallel.